# Hows authentication Sessions are maintained in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using the laravel Framework of php for development.I m using the authentication in-built feature to login the user .following are my questions:-

1. I want to know, how authentication class works and how it maintain authentication   session of the user,can i access that user and if yes,then how?
2. On laravel's Authentication Class's documentation page,it is written like

   > If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your application, you may pass >true as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated >indefinitely (or until they manually logout):

So, I want to know ,if i didnt specify the remember me , than how long my session gonna be there?

UPDATE :new problem

1. Also ,In my db i have table user_auth instead of Users table and when i try to use authentication class ,its  shows me error that users table is missing ,so after little effort ,i found and changed table name in auth.php in config folder ,but still its not working ,help me out?

Comment: In the auth.php config file, there are different aspects :
'model' => 'User',
'table' => 'user_auth',

check that you indeed have the model class model in models/
check that you indeed have the table user_auth table

I'm not sure why you would want to do a user_auth table,and not stick with a users table

Comment: @seblaze  ,i rechecked that model exist and code to change table name exist but still not working  and i need name user_auth as it in the schema provided to me ,i cant make change in that ,but this is very small customization ,laravel should support,but thanks my others question are resolved

Comment: did you checked that Users model uses the user_auth table ? does it have  protected $table = 'users_auth'; variable set?

Comment: yes bro, its set already by me :( still not working and dont know why

Comment: can you attach the exact error that it gives you ? and with what file ?

Comment: go here bro http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/a.html

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. Where does the error show up ? when you want to log in ? 
can you show me the config/auth.php also ? and user model ?

Comment: here are the links

[link](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/auth.txt)       
[link](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/user.txt)    
[link](http:/sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/UserController.txt)

Comment: here are the links

[link1](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/auth.txt)       
[link2](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/user.txt)    
[link3](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/UserController.txt)

Comment: here are the [Error](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/a.html)
[auth](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/auth.html)
[user model](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/user.html) 
[controller](http://sahilsethi.net46.net/stackoverflow/UserController.html)

Comment: i looked through logs, it seems that Auth is still loading the old config file . Please run php artisan dump-autoload , and composer dump-autoload . I'm  still not sure why it loads the users table

Comment: nothing happens ,please visit here [HERE](http://laravel.io/forum/04-12-2014-any-one-in-forum-can-solve-my-problem)    i also debug this problem at my end  and read this ,thanks for ur effots bro

Comment: did you checked for other overwritten config files ?

Comment: what config file bro?

Comment: auth.php , do you have any subfolder in the config folder ? i.e. config/local. Except config/packages and config/tests ?

Comment: i check ,nothing there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you can find](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593) a really nice tutorial regarding registering/authenticating/filtering based on authentication status.

To access the logged in user. You can check the [Laravel security page](http://laravel.com/docs/security) 
 Basically here :

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    $email = Auth::user()->email;
}
```

Regarding session parameters ( how many minutes the session lives, etc ) you can check out

```
app/config/session.php
```

And see more informations regarding sessions [here](http://laravel.com/docs/session)

Comment: see the question, again ,i m facing a new problme now ,help me out seblaze

Comment: replayed to your first post